# Ambiguous [combination] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-reorganization

See [combination](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combination) (113 threads). Some of these are combinatorics questions about counting combinations, some are about linear combinations, combining distributions, combining this, combining that... The tag has no wiki. I don't think this tag is very useful in any of its meanings.

#### Proposed way forward

- Those Qs that are about combinatorics should be retagged [combinatorics] or if both tags are present, the [combination] tag simply deleted. I don't think it is relevant to separate combinatorics questions that are about "combinations" from other combinatorics questions by tags.
- In other cases, the tag [combination] should on a case-by-case basis be either just deleted or retagged to something  more descriptive if there is something tag-worthy, say, [combining-forecasts].

Comment: +1. Would you be willing to do the job?

Comment: Not willing to commit any significant time but if this is agreed upon, I may process some questions every now and then

Comment: While going through the meta-analysis thread removing tags to do with weighting I noticed some questions tagged [combination]. This is tautologous, what is m-a after all except combination? When I get time I will delete the tags unless you get there first.

Comment: There is also a stray tag [combinatorial] with three threads.

Comment: All 3 [combinatorial]-questions seem to be about combinatorial optimization, perhaps that tag should be renamed combinatorial-optimization

Comment: I supplied a tag wiki excerpt saying `DO NOT USE THIS TAG: it is ambiguous and has no meaning. Use more specific tags instead (usually [combinatorics]).`

Comment: I have removed all (the handful) of [combination] tags from meta-analysis. Note that there is a tag [combining-p-values] which is distinct and valuable.

Comment: Somewhat related issue: There is a [tag:permutation] tag (261 threads) which is mostly used to refer to permutation-based hypothesis tests, but sometimes refers to combinatoric problems related to permutations. Perhaps it would make sense to remove it from the latter ones (replacing with [combinatorics]) and then rename the tag to [permutation-test]. I realize it is a separate issue, we can raise it on Meta once this one is resolved.

Comment: @amoeba There would be some synergy benefits from deciding the fate of [permutation] now, however.  While going through [combination] one could either  i) sometimes kill two tags with one stone or ii) sometimes add [permutation], depending on what was decided.

Comment: My own opinion is that [permutation] is as superfluous as [combination]; questions about permutations and combinations can be tagged with [combinatorics]. Questions about permutation tests should be tagged with [permutation-test]. I might raise it on Meta at some point, but for now I would simply remove [permutation] from combinatorics threads that you are editing.

Comment: Question posted: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4280.

Comment: @mdewey Thanks for your continuing effort in eliminating the [combination] tag. Don't forget to post an answer here announcing that this task is over once you are done.

Comment: @mdewey and Juho: By the way, I noticed that you are now using [linear-combination]. I am not convinced that it is a useful tag; do you think it is? Don't we have hundreds (or thousands) of threads on linear combinations without this tag? Can't we use [linear-algebra] when needed, which is an often used existing tag?

Comment: @amoeba I am perhaps over-reluctant just to delete [combination] without a replacement. Perhaps I should be more ruthless.

Comment: Juho, please see the updates to @mdewey's answer. [Combination] tag does not exist anymore, and the small sister tags have been cleaned up as well. Consider accepting his answer to mark this issue as resolved.

Comment: @amoeba Answer accepted, thanks for notifying me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This tag is now empty, and if I understand correctly will auto-delete. there remain a few with the tag linear-combination which as @amoeba pointed out could apply to most posts here so unless anyone objects in comments here I will deal with them in a few days unless anyone else like to do that.

Update: I have removed the [linear-combination] tag from all 8 which had it and in one case added [contrasts]. I think [combining-models] could be replaced with [model-averaging] without loss of information and perhaps some of [combining-estimates] and [combining-predictions] could be similarly re-tagged. The one which stumps me is [combinatorial]. I think it means something different from [combinatorics] but I do not really understand the area well. If nobody objects here I will do the re-tagging I suggest and hope someone else will pick up the [combinatorial] issue, perhaps by writing a wiki excerpt.

Final, I hope, update: I have now removed all of [combining-predictions] and [combining-estimates] so when the tag fairy sprinkles her magic dust on them the last one will disappear.

Comment: Great job. There is a couple of other minor tags starting with "combin", many of them without excerpts and of unclear usefulness. [combinatorial]  with 7 Qs and no excerpt; [combining-predictions] with 5 Qs and no excerpt; [combining-estimates] with 4 Qs; [combining-models] with 1 Q and no excerpt. I did not look at them, but I have a feeling most of them are not useful. What do you think?

Comment: @amoeba I will have a look and perhaps report back.

Comment: Have you had a chance to take a look? Somebody just posted a suggestion on Meta to delete [combining-models], so perhaps we should finish up this tidying...

Comment: @amoeba yes, I have been having a siesta. I will have a look tomorrow.

Comment: @amoeba what is the protocol for this? Do I need to post another question or, for instance, is it OK just to remove the tag from [linear-combination] which would not really affect any of them?

Comment: With [linear-combination] you can definitely go ahead already now (nobody objected since Sep 25, see your answer). With other mentioned tags, I'd say you can also go ahead; or perhaps edit your answer to announce what you are going to do unless nobody objects. This is not worth a separate thread.

Comment: @amoeba I have now removed [linear-combination] from all 8 and in one case replaced it with [contrasts]

Comment: (1) Consider updating your answer accordingly. (2) Do you have any opinion on the other `combining-` tags that I listed in the first comment above?

Comment: [combinatorial] is no more.

Comment: Now removed [combining-models] in one case replacing with [model-averaging]

Comment: Thanks for taking care of it, @mdewey.